# How to setup celery flower behind a proxy, without applicatio knowing it is behind proxy

Tags: celery, flower

Example -> example.com/flower
Reverse proxy rewrites this url via removing flower and sending to our flower instance but css etc. doesn't load

If we use --url_prefix this causes flower instance to expect urls with /flower while our reverse proxy overrides it

I want to have only css (static files) to be have /flower appened
A path prefix handled by a proxy that is not seen by the application but is seen by external clients.

Is there a way to achieve this?